# DocuSign error: This Account lacks sufficient permissions. In-Session permission required when specifying a captive recipient

Tags: docusignapi

When I send a SOAP request to DocuSign it is showing an error: This Account lacks sufficient permissions. In-Session permission required when specifying a captive recipient.

Full response XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<soap:Header>
    <wsa:Action>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/fault</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:9f406870-dc55-441d-b5ff-8317166636b9</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:b572d1a4-b8b5-4254-8f1d-7fd46fb593f1</wsa:RelatesTo>
    <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
    <wsse:Security>
        <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-656764ea-c0f0-4074-88b1-dbffae666a83">
            <wsu:Created>2013-08-01T18:00:46Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2013-08-01T18:05:46Z</wsu:Expires>
        </wsu:Timestamp>
    </wsse:Security>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
        <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
        <faultstring>This Account lacks sufficient permissions. In-Session permission required when specifying a captive recipient.</faultstring>
        <faultactor>https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx</faultactor>
        <detail>
            <ErrorCode xmlns="missing in Web.Config">111</ErrorCode>
            <ErrorReason xmlns="missing in Web.Config">This Account lacks sufficient permissions.</ErrorReason>
        </detail>
    </soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

A request we send is:

```
User-Agent: SFDC-Callout/28.0
X-DocuSign-Authentication: <DocuSignCredentials><Username>There is a user name</Username><Password>There is a password</Password><IntegratorKey>There is an integrator key</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
Accept: text/xml
Content-Type: text/xml
charset: UTF-8
SOAPAction: "http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0/CreateAndSendEnvelope"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<env:Header />
<env:Body>
    <CreateAndSendEnvelope xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
        <Envelope>
            <AccountId>There is an accountId</AccountId>
            <Documents>
                <Document>
                    <ID>1</ID>
                    <Name>Bayfront - Smoke free environment form - Antony.pdf</Name>
                    <PDFBytes>There is an encoded body</PDFBytes>
                    <FileExtension>pdf</FileExtension>
                </Document>
            </Documents>
            <Recipients>
                <Recipient>
                    <ID>1</ID>
                    <UserName>mikhail</UserName>
                    <Email>mikhail.ivanov@targetrecruit.net</Email>
                    <Type>Signer</Type>
                    <AccessCode xsi:nil="true" />
                    <RequireIDLookup>false</RequireIDLookup>
                    <CaptiveInfo>
                        <ClientUserId>1</ClientUserId>
                    </CaptiveInfo>
                    <RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder>
                    <RoleName>Signer</RoleName>
                </Recipient>
            </Recipients>
            <Tabs />
            <Subject>Please Sign this Document: </Subject>
            <EmailBlurb>This is my new eSignature service, it allows me to get your signoff without having to fax, scan, retype, refile and wait forever</EmailBlurb>
            <CustomFields>
                <CustomField>
                    <Name>DSFSSourceObjectId</Name>
                    <Show>false</Show>
                    <Required>false</Required>
                    <Value>Credential ID</Value>
                </CustomField>
            </CustomFields>
        </Envelope>
    </CreateAndSendEnvelope>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

What can be the reason? How should I fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately this is an account setting that can only be enabled from DocuSign's side.  We've configured new demo accounts to have this enabled by default, so not sure why it's not enabled for you, but please provide your account ID and I can turn it on for you.  Please note, however, that this is either an enterprise or workgroup level feature.  We let you test all features in the free demo accounts, but when you are ready to move to production you'll need to make sure you purchase an account that has this feature available, if you want to use it.

Comment: For more info on how that works please contact your DocuSign Account Manager.  If you do not have one please contact DocuSign Support.

Answer (score 3):

DocuSign developer sandboxes have this enabled by default so you can test Embedded Signing (and sending, etc) before going live.

In terms of live production accounts- not all accounts have embedding enabled so ensure you have purchased an account that has it.  If you are getting this error in production you most likely need to upgrade.