# ACCOUNT_LACKS_PERMISSIONS error when creating envelope

Tags: docusignapi

I am getting this error when creating an envelope

`DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiException: Error calling CreateEnvelope: { "errorCode": "ACCOUNT_LACKS_PERMISSIONS", "message": "This Account lacks sufficient permissions. In-Session permission required when specifying a captive recipient." }`

The problem occurs in the CreateEnvelope method when specifying a ClientUserId on the role which according to the Docusign documentation makes the recipient "embedded".

Docusign Support was unable to help and told me to post the problem here.

The odd thing is I have two accounts and this works on one of them. The working account is a Business plan and the one with the error is a Professional plan.

Is this a setting issue or a licensing level issue?

Comment: I ran into this with a sandbox account I'd created about 2yrs ago. It was working until maybe a month ago, then I started getting this issue. In my case, as it's a sandbox account and not a paid account, support wouldn't touch it so I ended up creating a new sandbox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless something's changed recently on the DocuSign side, there's a setting that DocuSign (either Support or your Account Manager, if you have one) can enable for your account such that you're allowed to create envelopes with embedded recipients via the API.  If you're using an account in the DocuSign "Demo" environment (i.e., developer sandbox), then this setting should be enabled by default.  But in the Production environment you'll likely need DocuSign to enable this setting for you.  Here's a related (old, but likely still relevant) post that describes the same issue and suggested resolution:

[DocuSign error: This Account lacks sufficient permissions. In-Session permission required when specifying a captive recipient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002360/docusign-error-this-account-lacks-sufficient-permissions-in-session-permission)

If/when you contact DocuSign support again, you may want to have them review that post, so that they'll have more context as to why you're receiving the error.  They're in the habit of referring folks to Stack Overflow for all API-related questions , but in rare cases (like this one), someone at DocuSign needs to update an account setting to resolve the API error.

Answer (score 1):

I called Docusign Support. They changed a setting called In Session to Enabled in API section near limiter that only the account manager or tier 2 support can change. All is well.

Answer (score 1):

If you do need to reach out to DocuSign, ask them to turn on a setting in your Account Plan Editor named "Enable In Session Signing"

As future reference, also be aware that if your DocuSign account has 21 CFR Part 11 module enabled, embedded signing is automatically disabled. Part 11 requires signers to log in to a DocuSign account to initiate signing and for each Signature field they sign in the documents -- so embedding signing is incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 22CFR11 enabled, Docusign may (will?) tell you that in session signing can't be enabled. They *do* have a way of doing embedded signing with 22CFR11 by authenticating users by SMS, but their admin tooling doesn't seem to allow them to set this up easily. Keep pushing them. (If I figure out the magic words, I'll update this!)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).