# Error when going live on Docusign API

Tags: docusignapi

After developing in the sandbox, we got our api key approved and promoted to a live account.

Since then we've been getting the following response -

response: {
 "errorCode": "ACCOUNT_LACKS_PERMISSIONS",
 "message": "This Account lacks sufficient permissions."
}
http code: 401
exeucted at: 2017-05-17 15:03:59

Based on my research and according to [ACCOUNT_LACKS_PERMISSIONS error when creating envelope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41385509/account-lacks-permissions-error-when-creating-envelope?noredirect=1&lq=1)

A setting needs to be switched on the backend at Docusign. The user mentions -

"They changed a setting called In Session to Enabled in API section near limiter that only the account manager or tier 2 support can change. All is well."

The account ID is 30953035
API username bcbffa28-a316-473e-b2b7-48d964d909a7
The API request is below. This was working just fine under a Demo account. I've even upgraded to the Intermediate API in the hopes that it will resolve my issues but no dice.

Support says that I need to post here...

Comment: Where is the API request?  You mention it in your post but I think you forgot to include it?  We need that to see what type of options/features you're trying to use in the request...

Comment: Ergin, It's too long to include in the post. Stackoverflow doesn't allow the number of characters. And since this is a live call, there are some identifying information such as my property address, etc. I have it attached to my case ID 03390218 . Obviously, no one on support will help with this case. So if you have an email address, I can send you the request file.

Comment: Also, the only communication point in all of your documentation about go live issues says to email go-live@docusign.net. Here is the result - The response from the remote server was:
450 4.1.1 <go-live@docusign.net>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table

Comment: Found your email on a github challenge and emailed you the request.

Comment: Hi Arvand, can you accept the answer I posted here for the benefit of our community?  I believe your issue was indeed related to a bad `baseUrl`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by a bad account `baseUrl` that's being used in the request.   When your integration performs authentication for a given user, if you are using Legacy auth (`X-DocuSign-Authentication` header) then you need to point to the following /login_information endpoint for the live system:

```
https://www.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information
```

When you get the response you then need to parse the `baseUrl` value that was returned and use that sub-domain for subsequent API requests.  (Note that there are multiple sub-domains in the live system such as NA1, NA2, EU, etc)

The `baseUrl` that's returned will look something like:

```
https://na2.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/12345/envelopes
```

Make sure you configure your code to read this sub-domain and use in subsequent requests, otherwise you if you simply use `www` for instance you will not be hitting the correct account endpoint and you'll receive the "Account lacks permissions" error you're receiving.

Comment: This answer solved my problem, but only because I set host as **eu.docusign.net**. www.docusign.net does NOT work when using PHP SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Ergin's answer seems to work; however, he does not state which part of the baseUrl to keep after parsing.  In his example the baseUrl = "https://na2.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/12345/envelopes"  In all subsequent calls after authApi.Login(); use "https://na2.docusign.net/restapi" as the URL and that should eliminate the error message.