# Going live with PHP SDK: Error 401 Unauthorized

Tags: php, docusignapi

After all the neccesary steps in Sandbox/Demo account my Integrator key was marked Live and I attached it to live account.

I am using **DocuSign PHP SDK** so I changed **API username**, **API password**, **API account ID** and **Host** to Live account credentials according to this [guide](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview) - *Post Go Live* steps.

[image: DocuSign API settings]

Anyway I am getting error **401 Unauthorized** when attempting to create Envelope (or anything else).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution:

When going live while using DocuSign PHP SDK, set **Host** parameter to `https://eu.docusign.net/restapi` or any other subdomain provided by DocuSign that suits you best (eu, na1 ,na2, etc...).

### Explaination:

When working with DocuSign PHP SDK, you don't need to do login request to retrieve `baseUrl` parameter for your actual request (ex: creating Envelope). Instead you set **Host** parameter right at the beginning of your code and don't care about `baseUrl` anymore.

And that is where the problem lies. WITHOUT SDK, you first do login request to `https://www.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information` to get back your `baseUrl` paramater (ex: `https://eu.docusign.net/restapi/v2/account/1234/envelopes`) and use that for actual request. So when working WITH SDK, set the subdomain of **Host** parameter to *eu*, *na1*, *na2* or any other valid value provided by DocuSign right away.

I found the solution thanks to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44119359/3970975