# I am getting below error while implementing Embedded Signing in Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I am getting below error while implementing Embedded Signing in Docusign

{ "errorCode": "ACCOUNT_LACKS_PERMISSIONS", "message": "This Account lacks sufficient permissions. In-Session permission required when specifying a captive recipient." }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ACCOUNT\_LACKS\_PERMISSIONS error when creating envelope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41385509/account-lacks-permissions-error-when-creating-envelope)

Comment: Also see this answer..  [DocuSign error: This Account lacks sufficient permissions. In-Session permission required when specifying a captive recipient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002360/docusign-error-this-account-lacks-sufficient-permissions-in-session-permission)

Answer (score 0):

Your account does not have the Embedded Signing feature enabled, you need to reach out through DocuSign Support or your Account Manager if you have one.  Note that embedded signing is not enabled on all accounts.